# Powershell apply verbosity at a global level

Tags: powershell, verbose

Imagine if you have a script containing a single line of code like

```
ni -type file foobar.txt
```

where the -verbose flag is not supplied to the ni command. Is there a way to set the Verbosity at a global PSSession level if I were to run this script to force verbosity? The reason I ask is that I have a group of about 60 scripts which are interdependent and none of these supply -verbose to any commands they issue and I'd like to see the entire output when I call the main entry point powershell script.

Comment: `$VerbosePreference='Continue'` `help about_Preference_Variables`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `$PSDefaultParameterValues`:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['New-Item:Verbose'] = $true
```

Set that in the Global scope, and then the default value of -Verbose for the New-Item cmdlet will be $True.

You can use wildcards for the cmdletsyou want to affect:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['New-*:Verbose'] = $true
```

Will set it for all New-* cmdlets.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Verbose'] = $true
```

will set it for all cmdlets.

Comment: I hadn't heard of $PSDefaultParameterValues before and this definitely works for New-Item. The problem is that I would have to add such a rule for each command that is available in powershell in order to cover those called in these 60 scripts and any future edits

Comment: Not true.  You can wildcard the cmdlets you want to set.  Updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I find myself hindered by the powershell versions I'm working with. Any idea how I could achieve same in powershell version 2? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808908/alter-behaviour-of-every-cmdlet-in-powershell-session-to-pass-verbose-flag

Answer (score 4):

You could also do:

```
$global:VerbosePreference = 'continue'
```

Works better then PSDefaultParameters as it tolerates function not having Verbose param.