# Alter behaviour of every cmdlet in Powershell session to pass verbose flag

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, verbose

If I wanted to alter the behaviour of every cmdlet in a Powershell session to pass verbose flag I could achieve this in Powershell v3 with **$PSDefaultParameterValues** like so

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Verbose'] = $true
```

What would be a possible workaround for Powershell v2?

Comment: `$VerbosePreference='Continue'`

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. This just sets my verbose preference against commands which already have the verbose flag passed to them.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a 'new' feature in PowerShell 3.0 and up: [about_Parameters_Default_Values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx%20about_Parameters_Default_Values)