# How to generate comprehensive log file from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, logging, deployment

I am trying to write a migration/deployment script to deploy an application to an environment (DEV, QA, PROD) and I need to be able to fully log all output.  This would include any status message I specifically put in the output stream (not a problem) as well as verbose output from all commands.  For instance, if I'm calling `Copy-Item`, I want the full listing of each item copied.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this throughout the entire script reliably.  In other words, I don't want to rely on including `-Verbose` on every command (as it could be missed when someone else maintains the script in the future).  I've been looking at things like `$VerbosePreference` as well as the possibility of calling my main cmdlet/function using `-Verbose`, with the hope being that either would apply to the entire script.  But that appears to not be the case.  While any `Write-Verbose` commands I use respect either approach, calls to `Copy-Item` only show the verbose listing if I specifically pass `-Verbose` to it.  I'm really hoping I'm just missing something!  Surely this is possible to do what I'm wanting!

Sample code:

```
function Main () {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Begin {
        Copy-Item C:\Temp\src\* -Destination C:\Temp\dest -Recurse -Force
        Write-Output 'Main output'
        Write-Verbose 'Main verbose'
        Child
    }
}
function Child () {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Begin {
        Copy-Item C:\Temp\src\* -Destination C:\Temp\dest -Recurse -Force
        Write-Output 'Child output'
        Write-Verbose 'Child verbose'
    }
}

$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Write-Output $VerbosePreference
Main
''
Main -Verbose

''
''
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
Write-Output $VerbosePreference
Main
''
Main -Verbose
```

Produces output:

```
SilentlyContinue
Main output
Child output

Main output
VERBOSE: Main verbose
Child output
VERBOSE: Child verbose


Continue
Main output
VERBOSE: Main verbose
Child output
VERBOSE: Child verbose

Main output
VERBOSE: Main verbose
Child output
VERBOSE: Child verbose
```

So, clearly `$VerbosePreference` and `-Verbose` are affecting the `Write-Verbose`, but that's about it.  The `Copy-Item` is not displaying ANY output whatsoever (though it will if I specifically use `-Verbose` directly on that command).

Any thoughts?  Am I going about this all wrong?  Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about leveraging...

> Tip: Create a Transcript of What You Do in Windows PowerShell
>
> The PowerShell console includes a transcript feature to help you
>   record all your activities at the prompt. As of this writing, you
>   cannot use this feature in the PowerShell application. Commands you
>   use with transcripts include the following:
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687007.aspx

... or the approaches provided / detailed here:

> Enhanced Script Logging module (automatic console output captured to
>   file)
>
> Automatically copy PowerShell console output to a log file (from
>   Output, Error, Warning, Verbose and Debug streams), while still
>   displaying the output at the console. Log file output is prepended
>   with date/time and an indicator of which stream originated the line
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enhanced-Script-Logging-27615f85
>
> Write-Log PowerShell Logging Function
>
> The Write-Log PowerShell advanced function is designed to be a simple
>   logger function for other cmdlets, advanced functions, and scripts.
>   Often when running scripts one needs to keep a log of what happened
>   and when. The Write-Log accepts a string and a path to a log file and
>   ap
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0

*** Update as per the OP comment***

See this discussion...

> Powershell apply verbosity at a global level
>
> where the -verbose flag is not supplied to the ni command.  Is there a
>   way to set the Verbosity at a global PSSession level if I were to run
>   this script to force verbosity? The reason I ask is that I have a
>   group of about 60 scripts which are interdependent and none of these
>   supply -verbose to any commands they issue and I'd like to see the
>   entire output when I call the main entry point powershell script.
>
> [Powershell apply verbosity at a global level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763707/powershell-apply-verbosity-at-a-global-level)
>
> Use PowerShell Default Parameter Values to Simplify Scripts
>
> Changing default parameter values
>
> When I was asked to write about my favorite Windows PowerShell 3.0
>   feature, my #1 $PSDefaultParameterValues came to mind immediately.
>   From my point of view, this was something I was looking for, for a
>   long time.
>
> How does it work? With $PSDefaultParameterValues, you can define
>   (overwrite) default values of parameters for Windows PowerShell
>   cmdlets.
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/03/use-powershell-default-parameter-values-to-simplify-scripts/

See also:

> Script Tracing and Logging
>
> While Windows PowerShell already has the LogPipelineExecutionDetails
>   Group Policy setting to log the invocation of cmdlets, PowerShell’s
>   scripting language has plenty of features that you might want to log
>   and/or audit. The new Detailed Script Tracing feature lets you enable
>   detailed tracking and analysis of Windows PowerShell scripting use on
>   a system. After you enable detailed script tracing, Windows PowerShell
>   logs all script blocks to the ETW event log,
>   Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational. If a script block creates
>   another script block (for example, a script that calls the
>   Invoke-Expression cmdlet on a string), that resulting script block is
>   logged as well.
>
> Logging of these events can be enabled through the Turn on PowerShell
>   Script Block Logging Group Policy setting (in Administrative Templates
>   -> Windows Components -> Windows PowerShell).
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/audit_script

Comment: Appreciate the quick response, but I don't see how any of these options would force all cmdlets to use verbose output? I reviewed all three, and tried out Enhanced Script Logging, but still had to manually add `-Verbose` to the end of my `Copy-Item` command to get item listing logged.

Comment: No worries, but you set the verbosity at the global level. See the added update for you.

Comment: Perfect! `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Verbose'] = $true` worked exactly as I needed.  Thanks!